# Where does Oracle Forms look for ActiveX dll and its dependencies?

Tags: dll, oracleforms

I've written a `dll` `ActiveX`, which, in turn, has some other `dll` dependencies. This `ActiveX` now has to be used by the client with `Oracle Forms 6i`, but they're having trouble with the integration. They get an error from `Oracle Forms Runtime`: xxxx - `Unable To Locate Component` referring to `EDSDK.dll`, which I use in the ActiveX `dll`.

Comment: Dependent DLLs are found the usual way, the operating system first looks in the directory that contains the EXE, then in the directories listed in the PATH environment variables.  It will *not* look in the directory that contains your ActiveX DLL, the usual problem.  Troubleshoot with SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: And should the ActiveX DLL be in the same place?

Comment: It is found through the registry, it can live anywhere.